# create onenote page fails with 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

GET call on section pages is successful but POST call to create fails with

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "20102",
    "message": "Die angegebene Ressourcen-ID ist nicht vorhanden.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "bd160b20-eefa-4dd4-b8bf-605621c94c9d",
      "date": "2019-04-02T13:57:46"
    }
  }
}
```

Request-id: bd160b20-eefa-4dd4-b8bf-605621c94c9d

Answer (score 0):

Double check the notebook key and sectionID you are using.  That message indicates one of these parameters is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not able to find any section with the given section Id. Do you have any kind of security policy enabled on that tenant?

Comment: Sorry, we are not storing request id for successful call,
But I can contact with our customer success team to get more context